# How to cool water inside an evaporative cooler

Tags: water, temperature

The temperature in our area is 34 C at noon time. I have an evaporative cooler. But I  am not satisfied with it. But when I pour some water from my refrigerator, it will give nice cool air. But it is not practical to depend refrigerator for every time. So I am searching for a method to cool the water inside the cooler's tank. It is in room temperature. I am considering peltier module for this, but don't know how to use it. All tutorials in net are about pc cooling. I can't find a peltier tutorial for water cooling. So I am here to find an easy method for cooling the water as instant as possible.

PS: I need the water to be cooled near 15-18 degree Celsius.

Comment: Unclear, needs editing.

Comment: The Peltier element is less efficient for cooling, maybe 10 times less efficient compared to the evaporative cooler.

Comment: I'm not sure this requires a lifehack...

Answer (score 4):

First, measure the water temperature after it's been circulating through the cooler's filter, with the fan running, for a while.  You'll find the water cools to the dew point fairly quickly (a figure that depends on the humidity) -- and it won't stay any cooler than that without spending energy continuously to refrigerate it.  In dry conditions, an evaporative cooler can in fact cool to around 15 C even when its 35 C outside (I've used them in these conditions).

If conditions are damper, you may find you can't cool much if any below ambient -- if the humidity is 100%, the cooler can't cool below the temperature of the air by evaporation; all the cooling you'll get is storing heat in the water, if it starts cooler than the air.

If you're in the latter state, you'd be ahead to buy (or build, if you're handy with tools and understand thermodynamics a bit) a simpler refrigeration cooler.  It will cool some number of degrees below ambient regardless of humidity (though it will require more energy to operate than an evaporative cooler).

One alternative, for short term, is a large ice block with a fan blowing past it.  This will cool very effectively, but the ice only last so long, and you're paying for refrigeration to make the ice (or buying it from someone who did).